# JSF + Primefaces - Dynamic include

Tags: jsf, dynamic, include, primefaces, tabview

Firstly, sorry for my english ^^
I've got problems with dynamic includes in my structure.

I've got a tabview, and the tabs are built dynamically..
The tabs are createed by different commandbuttons, and in one of my beans, are putted in one ArrayList of tab

This is the tabview:

```
<p:tabView value="#{indexBean.tabs}" var="tab" id="tabView" activeIndex="#{indexBean.selectedNewTab}"
```

And these are the tabs:

```
<p:tab title="#{tab.title}" closable="#{tab.closable}">
```

In the tab, I've got different .
I've got only one tab that is so defined:

```
<ui:include src="content/accordion.xhtml"/> 
<ui:include src="content/toolbar.xhtml"/>
<ui:include src="content/dataTableRawResults.xhtml"/> 
<ui:include src="content/dataTableCurves.xhtml"/> 
<ui:include src="content/dataTableReports.xhtml"/> 
<ui:include src="content/dataTableAdvancedStatistics.xhtml"/>
```

Every single page that is included has a rendered tag (in my bean I set different booleans so that I can specialize every that as I desire..)

That's work fine.. Except for one problem...
It is too slow!!

I suppose because of the rendering.. So I've tried different ways to solve it..

I tried with  .. With query in src tag of .. But nothing seems to work fine.. 
With query, I open correctly the first tab.. But when I open the second one, the first one takes the same include of the second one (like if its attributes have been overrided)..

Thanks to all!

If I haven't explain well, please ask me and I'll try to be more precise!

Answer (score 0):

If it is too slow maybe you could try to load the tabs dynamically by adding to your p:tabView the attribute dynamic="true":

```
<p:tabView dynamic=true ... >
```